# Calculate days between two dates in SharePoint

Tags: date, if-statement, sharepoint, formula

I have two date columns in SharePoint. Start Date and End Date.

I want to calculate the networkdays between these two dates. However, if the End Date is blank, I want it to use Today's Date and then calculate the network days.

=IF(End Date=" ",NETWORKDAYS(Start Date,TODAY()), NETWORKDAYS(Start Date,End Date))

It works when the End Date is populated but doesnt work when its Blank

Any help would be gratefully received. Thank you

Comment: Please try this: =IF(ISBLANK(End Date),NETWORKDAYS(Start Date,TODAY()),NETWORKDAYS(Start Date,End Date))

Comment: Are you trying it inside excel file or in SharePoint calculated columns?

Comment: Thank you @AmyJiang_MSFT. The formula works great in Excel but not in SharePoint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my knowledge, `NETWORKDAYS()` function is not supported in SharePoint calculated formulas.

But as you are saying it is working for you when End Date is populated but doesn't work when it is Blank, you can use the formula like below for condition when End Date column is blank:

```
=IF(ISBLANK([End Date]),NETWORKDAYS([Start Date],TODAY()), NETWORKDAYS([Start Date],[End Date]))
```

---

**Note**:

1. Sometimes comma(`,`) does not work in formula (it is based on language or regional settings on your site). So in that case use semicolon(`;`) instead of comma(`,`).
2. Use correct *display name* of your SharePoint columns in above formula.
3. Wrap column names inside `[]` if your column name has space in it. For example: `[My Column Name]`.

---

**Additional**:

If you are trying to get the days between 2 date columns including weekends, you can use `DATEDIF` function like:

```
DATEDIF([Start Date],[End Date],"d")
```

**Reference**: [SharePoint calculated column formula to get days between two date columns](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/309169/cannot-get-past-syntax-error/309170#309170)

If you are trying to get the days between 2 date columns excluding weekends, follow this: [How to create a SharePoint calculated column that gives date excluding weekends?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/309275/how-to-create-a-calculated-column-that-gives-date-excluding-weekends/309282#309282)

Comment: Thank you for your response. I tried in Excel with the hope of using the same in SharePoint but have come to understood that it doesnt work. I have retried your formula with datedif and it works beautifully. Thank you for your help Ganesh. Appreciate it.

Here is the formula
=IF(ISBLANK([End Date]),DATEDIF([Commencement Date],TODAY(),"D"),DATEDIF([Commencement Date],[End Date],"D"))